# Quick time event on Lara's first kill in Tomb raider definitive edition

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I am currently playing the Tomb raider 2013 on PS4, I've already beaten this game on 360. I've been stuck at a QTE when lara makes her first kill (mercenary) in the coastal forest level.

I don't remember running into this problem during my first play-through on Xbox. I manage to hit the triangle for the first 2 events correctly then for the next one i flick left /right on the left stick but nothing seem to improve my timing. I've been unsuccessful for over 30 attempts.

Is there a timing to beat this event? Has anyone encountered this before, these QTEs have already put a sour taste in my otherwise enjoyable campaign so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by switching the left stick to right hand which also was my dominant hand and used it to flick really quickly to get around it.

I did the same for all the subsequent QTEs later in the game successfully as well.